# Increment, decrement href in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pdo, slider, href

I have an image gallery that I would slide by two buttons.

The values from the database:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM struttura ORDER BY id_img";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
    $id_img = $row['id_img'];
    $file = $row['file'];
    $text = $row['text'];
    ?> 
    <li><img src="images/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($file, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>" id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($id_img, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>" /></li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

This is the div for navigation

```
<div class="navigation">
<a href="#" class="nav_prev js-shown">Prev</a>
<a href="#" class="nav_btn"></a>
<a href="#" class="nav_btn"></a>
<a href="#" class="nav_next js-shown">Next</a>
</div>
```

How can I increase or decrease the value of `href` in this way using JavaScript?

```
<a href="#1" class="nav_btn"></a>
<a href="#2" class="nav_btn"></a>
<a href="#3" class="nav_btn"></a>
...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with pure javascript

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName('nav_btn');
for(var i = 0; i< link.length; i++){

    link[i].href = '#'+(i+1);
    link[i].innerHTML = '#'+(i+1);

}
```

you can use jquery each loop

```
$( function(){

    $('.navigation').find('.nav_btn').each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('href','#'+i); // this will return from #0 you can this with '#'+i+1
    });

} )
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is get the total number of elements with the class as `nav_btn` 
using the

```
var x=$(".nav_btn").length;
```

You can then set a variable as `y=0`.On pressing the `next` button, you could increase it, and update the href.

If you ever need to change an attribute, there is a `setAttribute` method.

When you hit the max count(==length), reset to zero. Similar flow for previous button.

Also, I would **strongly suggest** you check the `next()` function in Jquery.Check link for documentation:[link](https://api.jquery.com/next/)